# Justification for g being a one to one function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

If $f$ and $f\circ g$ are one to one functions, is $g$ also a one to one function? Justify your answer.

I am guessing that $g$ should be a one to one function.

So a function $F$ is injective if:

$\forall a \forall b(F(a)=F(b) \Rightarrow a=b)$

So since $f$ is injective:

$\forall a \forall b(f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b)$

And $f\circ g$ is also injective:

$\forall a \forall b(f \circ g(a)=f \circ g(b) \Rightarrow g(a)=g(b))$

$\forall a \forall b(g(a)=g(b) \Rightarrow a=b)$

Does this show that $g$ must also be injective?

Comment: one to one means injective?

Comment: @LuckyS  That is correct.

Comment: You did not write the translation into symbols of "$f \circ g$ is also injective".  The symbols you wrote are another way to write "$f$ is injective" followed by "$g$ is injective" (and it is unclear what justification you used for the second).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You proof doesn't seems correct. Anyway, take $a,b$ such that $g(a)=g(b)$. So $fg(a)=fg(b)$. But $fg$ is injective, so $a=b$. The injective of $f$ doesn't seem important as hypotesis.

Comment: I'm confused. Does your answer say that $g(a)=g(b)$ implies that $fg(a)=fg(b)$? I thought injective functions were defined the other way round? ($fg(a)=fg(b)$ implies that $g(a)=g(b)$?

Comment: Oh I see, is it from the rules of inference? ((p implies q) and q) implies p?

Comment: @FarmerZee No. It is just direct: if $x=y$ then $f(x)=f(y)$, right? Taking $x=g(a)$ and $y=g(b)$ we get: if $g(a)=g(b)$ then $f(g(a))=f(g(b))$.

Comment: **ALL** functions satisfy $x=y \implies f(x)=f(y)$. That's the very definition of a function: every input has exactly one output. Now plug in $x=g(a)$ and $y=g(b)$. @FarmerZee

Comment: @LeeMosher Why is definition of an injective function be just an "one way" implication? If if we combine it the definition of a function, shouldn't it be defined using an if and only if?

Comment: In the definition of an injective function, first one is already *given* that $f$ is function, i.e. one is *given* that $x=y \implies f(x)=f(y)$; that's what the definition of a function says. Then one is defining the additional property of injectivity: $f(x)=f(y) \implies x=y$. So it's not necessary to include the definition of a function when defining injectivity.

Comment: It's often important, when reading a mathematical definition, to pay attention to what is given, and keep that apart from what is being defined. Well written mathematical definitions should make that distinction clear; poorly written ones may require you to read between the lines to tease out that distinction.

Answer (score 4):

Let's prove the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive)!  If $g$ is not injective, then there exist two distinct elements $a$ and $b$ in the domain of $g$ such that $g(a) = g(b)$.  Let $c = g(a)$.  Then $$(f \circ g)(a) = f(g(a)) = f(c) = f(g(b)) = (f \circ g)(b),$$ and so $f \circ g$ is also not injective.

Thus, if $g$ is not injective, then $f \circ g$ is not injective.  By contraposition, this is equivalent to the statement that if $f \circ g$ *is* injective, then $g$ is also injective, which we were asked to prove.

---

(Note that we did not, in fact, have to use the assumption that $f$ is also injective anywhere, and indeed the same result holds even if $f$ is *not* injective.  However, while $f \circ g$ being injective does *not* imply that $f$ is injective, we *can* prove that it implies that the [restriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)) of $f$ to the [range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_function) of $g$ must be injective.)